# Firebase upload with JavaScript fails

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, asyncfileupload

I am using js for the first time and i am clueless why my code isnt working. Maybe someone can help me with that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <script src="js/uikit.js"></script>
        <script src="js/uikit-icons.js"></script>

        <title>Face Recognition</title>
    </head>

    <body>


        <section>
            <a href="index.html">Back to home</a>
        </section>
        <input type="text" id="label" placeholder="Input name"/></br>
        <input type="file" id="photo"/></br>
        <button id="upload" onclick="uploadImage()"</button>

        <script type="module">
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-app.js";
            import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-database.js";
            import { getStorage, ref as refStorage, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-storage.js";

            const firebaseConfig = {
                my firebase config...;
            };
          
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            const db = getDatabase(app);
            const storage = getStorage(app);

            async function uploadImage(){
                const file = document.getElementById('photo').files[0];
                const label = document.getElementById('label').value;
                const storageRef = refStorage(storage, 'images/' + file.name);
                await uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then(async (snapshot) => {
                    console.log('File uploaded');
                    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
                    console.log('File at', downloadURL);
                    const dbRef = ref(db, 'images/' + label);
                    set(dbRef, {
                        name: label,
                        url: downloadURL
                    });
                });
            }
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried different approaches but i cant get i done on my own. I succeded in uploading the image to the storage before, but then i wasnt able to save the url to the img and the label in the real-time database.

This is the error in the browser console:

> project.html:59 Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadImage is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (project.html:59:146)

Comment: functions in `script type="module"` don't appear in the global scope, unless you specifically put them there - a better way to do this would be to use `addEventListener` rather than the `onclick` attribute

Comment: Is the rest of the code fine? Do i just have to replace onclick then? And do i have to call the attribute in the Upload function?

Comment: no idea what "call the attribute" means, nor if the rest of the code is right

Comment: i'll look into it tomorrow ty for now. maybe using the different attribute will already fix it

Comment: what attribute were you thinking of using?

Comment: nevermind, the answer from @Anh Nguyen Ngoc worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<script type="module">
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-database.js";
import { getStorage, ref as refStorage, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-storage.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
    // Your Firebase config
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

async function uploadImage(){
    const file = document.getElementById('photo').files[0];
    const label = document.getElementById('label').value;
    const storageRef = refStorage(storage, 'images/' + file.name);
    await uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then(async (snapshot) => {
        console.log('File uploaded');
        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
        console.log('File at', downloadURL);
        const dbRef = ref(db, 'images/' + label);
        set(dbRef, {
            name: label,
            url: downloadURL
        });
    });
}

// Attach the function to the window object
window.uploadImage = uploadImage;
```

Additionaly, please make sure that your button tag  is correctly closed like:

```
<button id="upload" onclick="uploadImage()">Upload</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine now. Can you explain me what this one line of code does?